# in facebook api How to attach a link or reference a page in message from php

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

In facebook api for php, we post a message on page or user wall. If we are updating status from facebook website, we reference a facebook page in our status as `@some_page`, but how to reference a page from php facebook message? I tried `@some_page` but it displays as a text, not a page link. [image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to surround the page-mention with brackets. Like `@[page-id]` or `@[page-url]`.

See also the [corresponding Open Graph API section](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/guides/tagging/#pages) on this topic.

Comment: That is not available for normal posts/status updates, only for Open Graph actions, and your action has to be approved by Facebook.

Comment: @CBroe @max-k the solution is not working for me, my page id is showing instead of tag. i.e `@[1234567]`.

Comment: can anyone tell me how to submit approval. As mentioned in docs, i checked my apps dashboard and unable to find any submission button or something realted

Comment: As I said, that kind of Mention Tagging is available for Open Graph actions only – so you would have to define actions for something the user can undertake in your app first (again, this is not for normal posts). https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/